# Set Username in jBoss custom login module

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I am working on enterprise application that has custom login module for jboss implemented. It has form based security login where user provides username and password. In login module credentials are checked against database and some addition checks are done. Now I want to enable user to login via a one time token ( some hash string for example: EF223222131) that I want to send him via email as URL: `applicationServer:8080/myApplication/login2.jsp?hash=EF223222131` .
On the page `login2.jsp` I have the same form for form based authentication, and I leave username and password blank, and add field hash. All fields are hidden and javascript fires form submit on page load. 
In login module I have managed to get hash:

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = 
    (HttpServletRequest)PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
    String hashV = httpRequest.getParameter("hashValue");
```

Then I get user from database set identity and role and `loginOk = true;` and `commitOk = true;` in respective methods. 
But in my web application username stays empty.
`httpRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName()` returns empty string. Also if I invoke EJB I get empty string from  `sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName()`.

Is there a way to set those values from Login module? Or is there an alternative approach for login via token in URL?

I am using jboss 4.0.3SP1 and java 1.4.2, but I think it should be the same as in the newer configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Subject object of the Login Module. In the `commit()` method, there was a code defining subject object:

```
if(!subject.getPrincipals().contains(identity)) {
        subject.getPrincipals().add(identity);
}
Group g = new SimpleGroup("Roles");
g.addMember(new SimplePrincipal((String) options.get("defaultRole")));
subject.getPrincipals().add(g);
```

When in addition I have added:

```
Group callerPrincipal = new SimpleGroup("CallerPrincipal");
callerPrincipal.addMember(identity);
subject.getPrincipals().add(callerPrincipal);
```

New username become available in session (from `httpRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName()` in servlets and from `sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName()` in EJBs)

I have found solution from the link: [Jboss community](https://community.jboss.org/message/132526#132526)